# PHP database using MVC framework getting an error message after running PHPUnit testing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpunit

When running PHPUnit it gives me this error, on all 5 tests any help would be much appreciated. This is my first time building anything in PHP and I know I have a long way to go.

```
Use of undefined constant MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT - assumed 'MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT' in all 5 tests.

At locations:
    mysql_connector.php:70 menu_controller.php:60
    mysql_connector.php:74 menu_controller.php:60
    mysql_connector.php:55 menu_controller.php:46
    mysql_connector.php:94 menu_controller.php:75
    mysql_connector.php:111 menu_controller.php:86
```

This is the MySql connector:

```
<?php
/**
* Class for creating, reading, and modifying the database.
*/
class Sql {
  /**
  * @var SELECT_ALL selects from database table.
  */
  const SELECT_ALL = 'SELECT * FROM';

  /**
  * Database constructor.
  * @param $user
  * @param $pass
  * @param $dbName
  * return void
  */
  function __construct( $user, $pass, $dbName ) {
    require_once 'meekrodb.2.3.class.php';

    $this->user = $user;
    $this->pass = $pass;
    $this->dbName = $dbName;
  }

  /**
  * Seaches database for user by id.
  * @param $databaseName
  * @param $field
  * @param $value
  * @return string
  */
  public function readByID( $databaseName, $field, $value ) {

    \DB::$user = $this->user;
    \DB::$password = $this->pass;
    \DB::$dbName = $this->dbName;

    $results = \DB::query( self::SELECT_ALL . $databaseName . 'WHERE' . $field . '=' . $value );

    return $results;
  }

  /**
  * Displays all users within the database.
  * @param $databaseName
  * @return string
  */
  public function readDb( $databaseName ) {
    \DB::$user = $this->user;
    \DB::$password = $this->pass;
    \DB::$dbName = $this->dbName;

    $results = \DB::query( self::SELECT_ALL . $databaseName );

    return $results;
  }

  /**
  * Creates a new user in the database.
  * @param $databaseName
  * @param $firstName
  * @param $lastName
  * @param $email
  * @param $password
  * @return string
  */
  public function create( $databaseName, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $password ) {
    \DB::$user = $this->user;
    \DB::$password = $this->pass;
    \DB::$dbName = $this->dbName;

    $results = \DB::query( 'INSERT INTO' . $databaseName . "( firstName, lastName, email, password ) VALUES ('" . $firstName . "', '" . $lastName . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $password . "' );" );

    return \DB::insertId();
  }

  /**
  * Updates a user within the database.
  * @param $databaseName
  * @param %id
  * @param $firstName
  * @param $lastName
  * @param $email
  * @param $password
  * @return string
  */
  public function update( $databaseName, $id, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $password ) {
    \DB::$user = $this->user;
    \DB::$password = $this->pass;
    \DB::$dbName = $this->dbName;

    $results = \DB::query('UPDATE' . $databaseName . "' SET firstName = '" . $firstName . "', lastName = '" . $lastName . "', email = '" . $email . "', password = '" . $password . "' WHERE Users.id = '" . $id . "';'");

    return $results;
  }

  /**
  * Deletes a user from the database.
  * @param $databaseName
  * @param $field
  * @param $value
  * @return string
  */
  public function delete( $databaseName, $field, $value ) {
    \DB::$user = $this->user;
    \DB::$password = $this->pass;
    \DB::$dbName = $this->dbName;

    $results = \DB::query('DELETE FROM' . $databaseName . 'WHERE' . $field . '=' . $value);

    return $results;
  }
}
?>
```

This is the controller:

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../models/user.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../mysql_connector.php';

/**
* Controller for functionality of menu
**/
class MenuController {
    /**
    * @var $db = database
    **/

    private $db;

    /**
    * @var TABLE = user table name.
    **/
    const TABLE = 'users';

    /**
    * Constructs database connector
    * @param none
    * return void
    **/
    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Sql('my_database', 'password', 'my_database');
    }

    /**
  * displays the user by id.
  * @param array $args
  * @return array
  */
    public function displayUserById(array $args = array()) {
        $id = $args[0];

        return json_encode($this->db->readByID( self::TABLE, 'id', $id));
    }

    /**
  * displays the database.
  * @param none
  * @return void
  */
    public function view() {
        return json_encode( $this->db->readDb( self::TABLE ));
    }

    /**
  * Creates a new user.
  * @param array $args
  * @return array
  */
    public function create(array $args = array()) {
        $firstName = $args[0];
        $lastName = $args[1];
        $email = $args[2];
        $password = $args[3];

        return $this->db->create( self::TABLE, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $password);
    }

    /**
  * Updates users within the database.
  * @param array $args
  * @return array
  */
    public function update(array $args = array()) {
        $id = $args[0];
        $firstName = $args[1];
        $lastName = $args[2];
        $email = $args[3];
        $password = $args[4];

        return json_encode( $this->db->update( self::TABLE, $id, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $password));
    }

    /**
  * Deletes a user within the database.
  * @param array $args
  * @return array
  */
    public function delete(array $args = array()) {
        $id = $args[0];

        return json_encode($this->db->delete( self::TABLE, 'id', $id));
    }
}
?>
```

My test folder:

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../controllers/menu_controller.php';

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

/**
* Extends PHPUnit giving access to the program, which allows for testing.
*/
class DatabaseTest extends TestCase {
  /**
  * Test to display if user was created.
  * @param none
  * @return true if user was created.
  * @test
  */
  public function testUserCreated() {
    $control = new MenuController();

    $results = json_decode( $control->create(['Jane', 'Doe', 'janedoe@gmail.com', 'password']));

    $this->assertTrue( $results > 0 );
  }
  /**
  * Test to display single user by id.
  * @param none
  * @return true if id was found.
  * @test
  */
  public function testShowUser() {
    $control = new MenuController();

    $newId = $control->create(['Jane', 'Doe', 'janedoe@gmail.com', 'password']);

    $results = json_decode( $control->displayUserById([$newId]))[0];

    $this->assertEquals($results->firstName, 'Jane');
  }
  /**
  * Test to display all user in the database.
  * @param none
  * @return true if users are displayed.
  * @test
  */
  public function testShowAllUsers() {
    $control = new MenuController();

    $results = $control->view();

    $items = json_decode( $results );

    $this->assertTrue(sizeof( $items ) > 1 );
  }
  /**
  * Test to update data of a user within the database.
  * @param none
  * @return true if user is updated.
  * @test
  */
  public function testUserUpdated() {
    $control = new MenuController();

    $results = json_decode($control->update([0, 'Jane', 'Doe', 'janedoe@gmail.com', 'password' ]));

    $this->assertTrue($results, "true");
  }
  /**
  * Test if user was deleted from the database.
  * @param none
  * @return true if user was deleted.
  * @test
  */
  public function testUserDeleted() {
    $control = new MenuController();

    $results = json_decode($control->delete([0]));

    $this->assertTrue($results, "true");
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe your test environment isn't configured correctly.

Comment: I added the test file if that helps, thank you for taking a look at it.

Comment: It is a possibility this is the first program I have created using PHP and PHPUnit I mostly just read tutorials and watched videos on how to configure everything.

Comment: It's often the case that your test config is slightly different than your development config, so don't forget to put in the right credentials for that as well. It seems odd you're using static strings in your `__connect` function, those should probably come from a config file somewhere.

Comment: Good to know I will look into creating a config folder and linking all of the files within a routes file. This is mostly just supposed to be a simple CRUD program with MVC framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is caused by the framework you are using. The constant itself is [predefined by PHP's MySQLi-driver](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php#constantmysqli-opt-connect-timeout). You could check the framework's manual if they recommend setting the configuration for the database driver to make that warning disappear. Another way would be to just set a timeout you deem reasonable in your test's setup:

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../controllers/menu_controller.php';

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

/**
 * Extends PHPUnit giving access to the program, which allows for testing.
 */
class DatabaseTest extends TestCase {

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        if (!defined('MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT')) {
            define('MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT', 3);
        }
    }

// ... your tests ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I applied that code and now I am getting an error message: Error: Class 'mysqli' not found on the same locations including the now locations in the meekroDB folder.

Comment: The locations specify the class mysqli and the query function `$mysql = new mysqli();` this is line 169

Comment: These are the locations of the errors from the terminal: `C:\Users\GitHub\Projects\database-project\meekrodb.2.3‌​.class.php:169 C:\Users\GitHub\Projects\database-project\meekrodb.2.3‌​.class.php:599 C:\Users\GitHub\Projects\database-project\meekrodb.2.3‌​.class.php:588 C:\Users\GitHub\Projects\database-project\meekrodb.2.3‌​.class.php:589 C:\Users\GitHub\Projects\database-project\meekrodb.2.3‌​.class.php:69`

Comment: OK, so I seemed to have fixed that issue by removing the semicolon in the php.ini file under extension=php_mysqli.dll. Now I am getting this error message: `ERROR: Unable to connect to MySQL server! Error: Access denied for user 'my_database'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` I will research that further.

Comment: Well, I don't see where you open the connection your Sql-class only has calls to `query`, so I can't really help with that. The message says `Access denied`. Are you sure `my_database` is the correct username? Check for where you connect to it: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: I am able to get it connected now just having more issues with my code at the moment. Trying to figure that one out. Thank you very much for the help that solution helped me fix my initial issue.

Comment: `QUERY: INSERT INTOusers( firstName, lastName, email, password ) VALUES ('Jane', 'Doe', 'janedoe@gmail.com', 'password' );'
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1` This is the error I am getting at the moment if you are able to help. doesn't give me much info to go off.

Comment: OK, I have figured it out and now all tests pass it was simply a syntax error where I had an extra "single" quotation mark within the line posted above. Thank you again for all of your help.